# Add text to the top of a page without the rest of the page being pushed down

Tags: html, css, accessibility

This should be a simple answer. I'm just not knowledgeable enough in CSS to know what to look for to fix this.

My employer wants me to add Skip to Content links to all the pages on our website as he's with a visual disability and it would improve accessibility by a lot.

I want to implement the method described here: http://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/#focus

My problem is that when the links gain focus, the rest of the page layout gets pushed down by a few pixels due to the text suddenly appearing. I want to have the text show at the top of the page without it affecting the layout below it. Can I fix the position of my layout somehow?

The entire layout is wrapped with a div container already, so I'm guessing it would just be a matter of adding a CSS property to that container that will fix it's position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this by absolutely positioning the link:

```
#skip a:active, #skip a:focus
{
position:absolute;
top: 0px; 
width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. The document and other elements behave like the absolutely positioned element does not exist, so this will add the link right at the top of the page, but should not cause the rest of the page elements to move.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix it, but it isn't allowing me to center the link at the top now that it's absolute. Is there a way to make the vertical position absolute but the horizontal position relative, i.e. centered?

Comment: Unfortunately the normal methods to center an element won't work for absolutely positioned items. The easiest thing in this case would probably be to make it the full width of the page and then center the text. I have updated my answer to do that - hope it helps!

Comment: You could throw a z-index of 999 to the above CSS